# Writing a Mobile Application for: Androis, iOS and Windows three times?

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have developed an auto ad website for some clients, some time ago. They now want a mobile app for their website.

This Mobile App would allow users to add their auto ads and search existing ads ... common things like this.

The Question: The only way to make the App compatible with Androis, iOS and Windows is to write it Three times, in their respective languages and "studios" ? Isn't it a compatible language for all 3, like Java or something like this ?

Or maybe jquery-mobile would give me this cross-platform compatibility ?

Thank  you for any help or advice you may have.

Answer (score 2):

i would recommend [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), it cross platform for Android, IOS, and Windows phone. Unlike others RN is not hybrid but render its component as native component.

Comment: Yes, after reading some preliminary stuff I think React Native would be the best choise.
After it's done, the app written on React Natice can be approved by Apple Store? because I know they are very restrictive with the apps they put on their store (unlike Android)

Comment: Also, is Atom / Nuclide the best IDE choice for staring coding the app on Windows? (thats my OS)

Answer (score 1):

The word you are finding here is "Hybrid App". Which means single codebase for all mobile platforms.
There are many good frameworks available to develop a hybrid app.

Below are the useful links for it:

http://developer.telerik.com/featured/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app/

https://www.sitepoint.com/top-7-hybrid-mobile-app-frameworks/

IONIC is my personal favourite.

Comment: The first article has been great for reading and I advise all mobile-app starters to read it before staring up. Very instructive, thanks Satish!

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you from my experience and knowledge that there are two types of Hybrid apps-

1. Webview app:
   The app will be simply a responsive website sitting inside a web view. The short

   eg. [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/)
2. Hybrid native app: 
   The app will have native components and will be indistinguishable from original native apps.

   eg. [React native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/), [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/)

Please go through [this article](https://medium.com/react-id/ionic-framework-hybrid-app-vs-react-native-4facdd93f690#.z7c3tqjzq) for better understanding

Comment: A Hybrid native app can be published on respective stores:  android, apple, windows ? - thanks. What about Webview app ?

Comment: and secondly, both methods would allow me to connect with website's MySQL server ?

Comment: If you use the known web view app frameworks like Phonegap or ionic then they are surely allowed by apple review process. And about MySQL server, both can use web API very well so you won't get any problem about it.

Comment: But webview apps may have limitations on how nicely it can use native features like device sensors. And problem with both kind of apps is that they are new to market and you will seldom find third party frameworks to use.

Comment: Reading the articles indicated above I decided to create the Hybrid Native, through React Native, because it seems that Webview apps are not received very well by the app stores: "If you want to distribute your application via an app store, you must build a hybrid or native application. You cannot distribute websites through app stores; that’s what your browser’s address bar is for!" - found it here: http://developer.telerik.com/featured/what-is-a-hybrid-mobile-app/ (indicated by other user)

Comment: Also, I based on Windows, and as for IDE I think will go with Atom/Nuclide for React Native dev of the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hybrid app using `jquery mobile, ionic, react native` and use the same code to build app for `Android, IOS and Windows`.

Comment: So I write the code with React Native (I think I'll go with this one) and after this I somehow export it or compile it for 1) iOS 2) Android 3) Windows mobile platofms ? and then I sumbit the versions to their respective stores ?

Comment: Yes... You write the hybrid code.. and build app using individual sdk's and submit them to different stores.